# Do url rewriting with $_GET with Google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, url-rewriting

URL rewriting with Google App Engine in php

Hello,

I am a student and I choose to put a website that I did on google app engine (GAE). I did it and everything works except that the app.yaml's url rewriting doesn't work with $_GET variable and GAE doesn't use Apache, so I can't use .htaccess file to do url rewriting.

So I do this post to ask help about this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/mod_rewrite?hl=en) on the official GAE documentation because I don't really understand it and make it works.

I dit this with my app.yaml file

> -url : /articles/.*
>    Script : 'mod_rewrite.php';

PS : The result that I would like to have is  /articles/14 and not /articles?id=14 in my url but with the URL /articles/14 it doesn't find $_GET (logic)

thanks